# Html file display is unwanted data

Tags: php, html

```
<td width="13%" style="padding-left: 3px;">Software</td>
<td width="10%" style="padding-left: 3px;">Hardware</td> 
<td style="padding-left: 3px;">
<div class="nobreak">ABCD</div></td>
<td style="padding-left: 3px;">SoftwareName<div class="nobreak">---</div></td>
```

/*In software name it is displaying  â€Œâ€‹ instead of --*/

Comment: software name is dynamic or static ? put complete details.

Comment: Software name is dynamic. I am dynamically adding that value into html file..

Answer (score 1):

check your html page charset it should be  `charset="UTF-8"`

Answer (score 0):

If your database is UTF-8, it's ok for mysql.

For your echo, if you do it in a web site, put this in the top page:

```
header('Content-Type: text/html; charset=UTF-8');
```

Or you can set meta for utf

```
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
```